# DAX, IF function, use two types of data types (numeric and text)

Tags: if-statement, text, numeric, dax

I wonder if you can use two kind of data types in the DAX, IF formula.

I want to calculate the EPS value. If it's positive, I want to return the value.
If it's negative, I want to show "`(d)`" as deficit.

Example code:

```
=IF([EPS]<=0;"(d)";
IFERROR([EPS];BLANK()))
```

But I only get the following error message:
"The second and third arguments of function IF have different data types"

Is there a workaround of this or a any ideas how I can combine the text and numeric data type in the IF function?.

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with PowerPoint?  If not, you might want to remove the powerpoint tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power Pivot for Excel 2016 and in Power BI Desktop can have an IF() function with multiple return types. In 2013, this is not currently possible.

Comment: Thanks for information, I didn't know that!. Then I will try to get a copy of the 2016 version of Office :)

Answer (score 2):

Try =IF([EPS]<=0,"(d)")

Note that no value has been specified for **value_if_false**. Therefore, the function returns the default, which is an empty string.